# toArray() method in Collection class

Tags: java, generics, collections

In `Collection` class are 2 `toArray()` methods: `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` and `Object[] toArray()`. There is no `E[] toArray()` method. Why?
It is connected with type erasures, but there is for example method - `boolean add(E e)`. Why is it possible to create parametrized `add` and it is not possible to create `toArray()` method?

Comment: Little happy with the backticks?

Comment: Could you explain more? What is wrong with backtick :p ?

Comment: Nothing wrong, I'm just giving you a hard time :) It's just rare to see so many in such a small space.

Answer (score 11):

> There is no E[] toArray() method. Why?

There's no way it could *actually* create an `E[]` at execution time, because it wouldn't know the type of array to create, due to type erasure.

The `add` method will *really* accept anything, but the compiler just checks that the argument type is compatible with `E` first. Nothing needs to be known at execution time. Likewise for something like `List.get`, the compiler inserts a cast into the *calling* code:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("hello");
String first = strings.get(0);
```

is compiled to the same code as this pre-generics code:

```
List strings = new ArrayList();
strings.add("hello");
String first = (String) strings.get(0);
```

Now that's fine here, because we know the `String` type at execution time in the calling code... but in `toArray()`, the code creating the array needs to know the type... and type erasure means that it doesn't actually know that. The array which is passed into `toArray()` allows it to create an array of the same type. Indeed, the *actual* type of the object created can be shown to depend on the array you pass in:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
        objects.add("xyz");

        Object[] array1 = objects.toArray(new String[0]);
        Object[] array2 = objects.toArray(new Object[0]);
        System.out.println(array1.getClass()); // class [Ljava.lang.String;
        System.out.println(array2.getClass()); // class [Ljava.lang.Object;
    }
}
```

If we'd passed in `new Integer[0]` it would have *compiled*, but then we'd have got a `ClassCastException` when `toArray` tried to cast a `String` (the only element) to `Integer`.

Comment: Am I correct? Shortly: `add` method can be checked by compiler, so there can be parametrized type. 'toArray` method can be also checked by the compiler, but it gives nothing, because due to type erasures returned type will be always array of Objects? It could be created, but it would be useless. Parametrized type is in `add` method, because there compiler can check parameter and it is useful.

Comment: @Pawel: Sort of. It's really to do with what can be checked and *when*. I'm not *quite* sure I follow your thoughts exactly, but hopefully they're in line with the answer :)